# $h^{n} = f$, $h$ and $f$ entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots

I found this exercise.

Let $f$ be an entire function and $n$ a positive integer. Show that there exists an entire function $h$ such that $h^{n} = f$ if and only if the orders of the zeros of $f$ are all divisible by $n$.

If $f$ has finite order we can apply Hadamard factorization theorem and we conclude. But what about the case ord($f$) = $\infty$ ?

Comment: Does order here refer to the order of each individual zero or the total number of zeroes?

Comment: the order of each individual zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one direction is clear, if $f = h^n$, then the multiplicity of each zero of $f$ is $n$ times the multiplicity of the corresponding zero of $h$.

For the other direction, consider the logarithmic derivative,

$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$

has only simple poles, in the zeros of $f$, whose residue, the multiplicity of the zero, is always a multiple of $n$. Therefore

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$

is an entire meromorphic function with only simple poles, and the residue in each pole is an integer.

Fix a $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z_0) \neq 0$, and for every $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus f^{-1}(0)$, choose a path $\gamma_z$ from $z_0$ to $z$ that passes through no zero of $f$. For two such paths $\gamma_z,\, \tilde{\gamma}_z$ the composition $\omega_z = \gamma_z\cdot \tilde{\gamma}_z^{-1}$ is a closed path, and

$$\int_{\omega_z} g(\zeta)\,d\zeta = 2\pi i\sum_{f(w) = 0} n(\omega_z;w)\cdot \operatorname{Res}\left(g;w\right) \in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}.$$

Hence

$$h_0(z) = \exp \left(\int_{\gamma_z} g(\zeta)\,d\zeta\right)$$

is well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus f^{-1}(0)$, independent of the choice of the path $\gamma_z$.

The quotient

$$\frac{f(z)}{h_0(z)^n}$$

is constant, as can be seen by differentiating: $h_0'(z) = h_0(z)\cdot g(z)$, and thus

$$\begin{align}
\left(f(z)h_0(z)^{-n}\right)' &= f'(z)h_0(z)^{-n} - n f(z)h_0(z)^{-(n+1)} h_0'(z)\\
&= f'(z)h_0(z)^{-n} - n f(z) h_0(z)^{-n} g(z)\\
&= h_0(z)^{-n}\left( f'(z) - n f(z)g(z)\right)\\
&\equiv 0.
\end{align}$$

Therefore the zeros of $f$ are removable singularities of $h_0$, and when removed, they are zeros of the continuation $\overline{h}_0$. Multiplying $\overline{h}_0$ with an appropriate nonzero constant produces an $n$-th root $h$ of $f$.